# Can't add UIScrollView to another UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I tried hard but was not able to add a vertical scrollView inside another horizontal scrollView with paging enabled. I tried searching for a solution but none were helpful. Please help.
Thanks.
Following is the code i have tried:

for (int i = 0; i < kNumImages; i++)
    {

```
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dots.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    UIScrollView *insetScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    insetScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    UIView *insetView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];


    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*i, 300, 300, 21)];
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.text = @"MyRandomText";
    UIImageView *imageButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 320, 260);

    [insetView addSubview:imageButton];
    [insetView addSubview:textLabel];
    [insetScrollView addSubview:insetView];
    [mainScrollView addSubview: insetScrollView];
    [mainScrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you're all insetScrollView set  frame origin x=0?

so try this.

```
UIScrollView *insetScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320*i, 0, 320, 300)];
```

---

```
 mainScrollView<->
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||   inset0      |   inset1        |    inset2     |   inset3      |   inset4   ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
||               |                 |               |               |            ||
```